# Atlas and county level data, but creating maps zoomed out to the entire U.S map

Tags: qgis, shapefile, atlas, qgis-atlas

I am using QGIS 3.16.12.

I have a dataset of 150 retail companies, each selling a product over 100 counties across the country. This dataset also includes data on the number of sales per county for each company. I merged this dataset into the U.S counties shapefile. Below is an snapshot of the shapefile attribute table.

[image]

I’d like to create a map per company (150 maps in total) using Atlas that indicates the number of sales across the U.S. For instance, when I generate company A's map using the entire country's map (like the snapshot below), I'd like to see the number of sales at the county level that it operates regardless of how many counties it's operating in. In order words, I don't want the maps get zoomed into only the counties that it operates, but rather I want to see it across the entire country's map so I can do a comparison between companies country wide like this:

[image]

Could you please tell me what steps I need to do next in order to achieve what I am intending to do? because when I select the shapefile mentioned above in Atlas as coverage layer and Company_ID as page layer, it doesn't uniquely identify each company like the image here:

[image]

Comment: To clarify, you want to have a separate sales map for each company, controlled via Map Atlas?

Comment: A map for the whole US, but down to county level... what page size will the map have?

Comment: please don't delete and repost questions - it will be viewed as spam by the system if you do it too often

Comment: @Cushen: that is correct. I want a separate sales map for each company. I believe I need to use map atlas otherwise it would be hard to manually make 150 maps.

Comment: @Erik: Does page size make a difference? I want a high resolution map if possible,  but I am not concerned about page size at this time, so any size works.

Comment: @Erik Is there any way to accomplish what I am trying to do? Any hint would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sure there is, but the map wont be very useful, since it either is so large you have to search forever, or the features are so small, you wont be able to see relevant information.